# Configure Komodo Edit for Python 3.2

Tags: python-3.x, komodo

I've installed Python3.2 for Komodo Edit 7 but can't get KE to recognise it. Under Edit, Preferences, Languages, Python 3 I've pointed it at my interpreter "C:\Python32\python.exe".

I've tried different versions of the following for a run-command, to no avail:

python3.2 "-u" "%F"

I also tried changing the default Python interpreter but it says "it's version 3.2 and won't run Python 2".

If necessary, I'm happy to replace Python 2.7 entirely with 3.2 - if someone offers these instructions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to change my PATH settings to use Python 3.2, rather than 2.7. I can leave my run-command as:

```
%(python) "-u" "%F"
```

and it uses the default (3.2) interpreter. The path can be changed from within Komodo Edit via Edit, Preferences, Environment.

Despite appearances, I don't believe it is possible to switch between Python versions in Komodo Edit 7 without changing the default interpreter. However, a simple PATH change is all that is required. [It's probably even possible to create a batch file that will switch the path between the two versions.]

I hope that this information may be of use to someone else. Andy.

Comment: I figured this out just now.. but would that not be possible in a ktf file with a short-key binding.. or at least that is my flow of thinking atm as seen here at https://stackoverflow.com/q/59340807/8928024