# how to set and run different python3 environment versions from komodo edit while in anaconda\env?

Tags: python, editor, komodo

How do I set the command run tool for a second environment of python in Komodo Edit?

By default the windows environmentals guide Komodo to `X:\folder1\Anaconda\python.exe` (py version 3.7.4, MKL 2019.10(service 2.3.0).

Let say I have: `X:\folder1\Anaconda\envs\MKL2018` and includes python version 3.6.4. and MKL 2018.0.2 (service 1.1.2) From below cmd-line instructions at the Anaconda command prompt I get the expected result:

```
conda activate MKL2018

python X:\folder2\Examples\LookupTable.py
```

> File : LookupTable.py | "python version" : 3.7.4.
>
> ..snippet...

But not from the editor when I try to implement the python path to `X:\folder1\Anaconda\envs\MKL2018`. Changing `%(python3)` to `%(X:\folder1\Anaconda\envs\MKL2018\python3)` doesn't work.

The ktf-file I have is as follows:

```
komodo.doCommand('cmd_saveAll');
ko.run.output.kill(-1);
setTimeout(function(){
   ko.run.runEncodedCommand(window, '%(python3) \"%F\" {\'cwd\': u\'%D\'}');
}, 100);
```

I assume I have to change something there and save the ktf under another name (e.g. mklpy)... but what to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was quite cumbersome to find a fitting short-cut solution (keeping it in the python3 environments) but if you don't use python version 2.x any longer and haven't installed it; the following can be done:

1. Go to Edit\Preferences
2. then under subheading "Languages" go to "Python" Default Python Interpreter
3. here you select the right path, for example "X:\folder1\Anaconda\envs\MKL2018\python.exe"
4. apply and close the tab.

Thereafter you can create a new ktf-file with:

```
komodo.doCommand('cmd_saveAll');
ko.run.output.kill(-1);
setTimeout(function(){
   ko.run.runEncodedCommand(window, '%(python) \"%F\" {\'cwd\': u\'%D\'}');
}, 100);
```

... now keep in mind to use the `'%(python)` instead of `'%(python3)`

... voila and you're done...