# How do I get pygame to run in Komodo?

Tags: python, pygame, python-module

I am using a Mac with Catalina 10.15.2. I recently installed Python 3.7.3 using Pyenv. My interpreter is Komodo Edit 12.
I have installed pygame by running:
`pip3 install pygame`

My issue is with Pygame. Whenever I try to execute:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pygame
```

Komodo returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/wetherman/Desktop/RandomPy/game.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

The unusual part, I think, is when I type `python3` in terminal, followed by `import pygame` it seems to work completely fine. But, when I start the Python Unix Executable from `/usr/bin/`, I get the same error that I got earlier in Komodo.

Comment: when you type `python3` in terminal, what version of Python is reported by the introductory text? In a script, what does `import sys` and `print(sys.version)` show?

Comment: Also, have you had this problem installing any other third-party Python libraries?

Comment: Can you check what interpreter is Komodo using? It might use python 2.7 so it doesn't know about the packages installed with pip3. Take a look at this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59340807/how-to-set-and-run-different-python3-environment-versions-from-komodo-edit-while) for some more help.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the version reported is 3.7.3 Print(sys.version) says the same.  I haven't tried installing any other libraries.

Comment: @AdrianPop that's also part of the issue, I dont know the location of ```python3``` other than /usr/bin. But the executable in /usr/bin won't import pygame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by changing: `#!/usr/bin/env python3`
To:  `#!/users/$(myaccountname)/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/bin/python3`

Answer (score 0):

Try this to install pygame:

```
import subprocess
import os

try:
    subprocess.call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'pygame'])
    import pygame
    print('Pygame installed.')

except ModuleNotFoundError:
    try:
        subprocess.run('pip install pygame', shell = True)
        import pygame
        print('Pygame installed.')

    except ModuleNotFoundError:
        print('Pygame could not be installed.')
```

Comment: I'm kind of a newbie to this stuff, do I put that into a .py file and start it?

Comment: @TristanDaivs yes, that should do it.